# How to test pattern regexpr in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have a string containing a pattern `'/^\d{7,15}$/'` and I would test string str1

How can I use this string `'/^\d{7,15}$/'` ???

```js
var re = '/^\d{7,15}$/';
var str1 = '12345678'; //should match!

// none of the below methods is working to me

var m1 = str1.match(re); 
console.log(m1); //null

var regex1 = new RegExp(re);
var t1 = regex1.test(str1); 
console.log(t1); //false
```

Comment: This first matches https://regex101.com/r/0sWP56/1

Comment: `new RegExp` expects an expression with no delimiters. Can you modify the string at the source so that it has no `/`s? If not you would need to strip them off first to use that.

Comment: remove the `'`s from `re` as at the minute it's a string

Comment: Or, if you can just construct a RegExp without using a string, do that: `var re = /^\d{7,15}$/;`.

Comment: Closing as typo! `:)`

Comment: I wouldn't call it a typo, since all previous comments are still missing the mark.  OP might not realize that `"\d"` isn't the same as `/\d/`.

Comment: @Scott Alright. But that definitely is a simple error.

Comment: @AndrewBone he wants to construct it using a string

Comment: I don't think it's a typo either, and nobody has answered his question fully yet, which is how to use that string as a RegExp, not how to create a RegExp in the first place. If he has a string in a variable, being able to construct a separate RegExp will not help him. He needs to do something like `new RegExp( str.substr( 0, 1).substr(0,-1));`. Hardly a typo.

Comment: the problem is exactly that described in the question ... I do not write the pattern, but the string pattern comes from the outside ... that's why I think the problem is reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash `\` in your string literal:

```js
var re = '^\\d{7,15}$';
var str1 = '12345678'; //should match!
var regex1 = new RegExp(re);
var t1 = regex1.test(str1);

console.log(t1);
```

I also removed the slashes `/` around your expression, as they are not required.  As Paulpro mentions in the comments, if you do not control the input string, you can strip them out with `str1.slice(1, -1)`.

Comment: Just need to remove the apostrophes

Comment: If the string is dynamic, how will you construct a regular expression object then?  Changing the string to a regex literal doesn't answer the question.

Comment: thank you :) works by stripping the string patter with str1.slice(1, -1).   however it seems to work even without escaping the backslashes